# JAX-RS Param Converter- Compile time error using it

Tags: rest, api, jax-rs, converters

This is my param converter

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

public class MyParamConverter implements ParamConverter<Sort> {
    @Override
    public Sort fromString(String s){
        return new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "ds"));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Sort mo){
        return mo.toString();
    }

}
```

this is my paramconverter provider

```
@Provider
public class MyParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider {

@Override
public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
    if(rawType.equals(Sort.class)){
        return (ParamConverter<T>) new MyParamConverter();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am trying to use in my API as

```
@GET
@Path("/")
Response read(@QueryParam("sort") Sort order);
```

I am expecting the jax to map string that I pass in my url e.g. `&sort="asc"` to Sort object. But I am getting an compile time error that `have a registered implementation of paramconverter provider`. I need to find a way when I pass a query param as `&sort="somethung"` it gets convert to `SORT` automatically either by using custom annotation or by using `Param Converter`.

Comment: have you registered your provider?

Comment: @sschrass. Thats the problem. I do not know what to do in order to register provider.

Answer (score 0):

with reference to your comment, try registering your provider like:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MyParamConverterProvider.class);

        return classes;
    }
}
```

or, if you are using Jersey

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        packages("my.package");

        // or without package scanning
        register(MyParamConverterProvider.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. I will try using it now. Can you tell me the import for ResourceConfig or maven dependency for Option 1 of your answer.
Because I am afraid I am using wrong one.

Comment: Because when I use option one it says can not override getClasses() as its final in super class

Comment: I recommend using Jersey. There is also a Spring-Boot starter for it as seen in this tutorial: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-boot/spring-boot-jersey-example/ otherwise add your dependencies to your question, it is hard to figure out what exactly you are using.

Comment: This is my import

Comment: POM Dependecy
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!-- uncomment this line and comment out jersey-container-servlet to see this break -->
    <!-- <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId> -->
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: import is import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

Comment: You're on Jersey, use the second approach.

Comment: I tried using. But it won't work. :(..It gives the same compile time error...
What do I need to do to use approach1 ?